# Apk android encryption

Tags: android, eclipse, encryption

Since about 1 or 2 weeks, I updated android on eclipse (android SDK Tools, Tools platform, etc ...). I use a software called "apk editor translator" to directly edit items in my apk applications (In my case doing translations). The applications that I translated (mine) are signed. I had no problem before, but since this update, I have not the ability to change that. This may be due to encryption when creating the APK ?
Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> This may be due to encryption when creating the APK ?

APKs are not encrypted by the build tools. That being said, you can't change a signed APK without resigning it.

> Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Talk to the developers of the tool that you are using and ask them. We are not tech support for unidentified tools.

Or, use string resources, rather than hand-editing compiled APKs.